# Joining multiple lines from the same table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to query a DB with this type of structure

```
table1

ID -> int
name -> varchar

table2

ID -> int
name1 -> int
name2 -> int
name3 -> int
```

Where name1 to 3 are table1 IDs. Each line of table2 can have 1 to 3 lines of table1 associated to it and, importantly, the IDs CAN be duplicated (e.g.: name1 and name3 could be the same). The fields are guaranteed to be filled in order (i.e.: if `name2` is NULL `name3` will also be).

I'm querying the DB like this, in order to get the strings associated to the IDs in the 3 columns:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t1a.name n1, t1b.name n2, t1c.name n3   
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1a on t2.name1 = t1a.ID,
LEFT JOIN table1 t1b on t2.name2 = t1b.ID,
LEFT JOIN table1 t1c on t2.name3 = t1c.ID
```

I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this doing only one LEFT JOIN, or if you could suggest a better table design strategy to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mix up `table1` and `table2` in the structure (or the query)? `table2` doesn't have a column `name` and the joins look backwards

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: ops, sorry, I'm correcting it!

Comment: I corrected the queries. Sorry, the actual table structure is way more complex, I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible and copy/paste is evil... :P

Comment: There really is no simple means to suggest a better design because of the generic nature of the question. It is akin to asking how best to to create a design to store widgets and dohickeys.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T1.ID
    , Min( Case When Z.ColNum = 1 Then Z.Name End ) As n1
    , Min( Case When Z.ColNum = 2 Then Z.Name End ) As n2
    , Min( Case When Z.ColNum = 3 Then Z.Name End ) As n3
From Table1 As T1
    Left Join   (
                Select ID, 1 As ColNum, name1 As Name 
                From Table2 
                Where name1 Is Not Null
                Union All 
                Select Id, 2, name2 
                From Table2 
                Where name2 Is Not Null
                Union All 
                Select Id, 3, name3 
                From Table2 
                Where name3 Is Not Null
                ) As Z
        On Z.ID = T1.ID
Group By T1.ID
```